# Why are file mounts outside of fileadmin not visible for users?

Tags: typo3, user-permissions

I tried to create a file mount to set access rights for a user.

Directory:

```
 typoroot/uploads/
```

I have set the file mount as absolute with an absolute path to that directory. With an without trailing an leading slashes.

Then I set the file mount for that user.

The file mount is not visible for the user. Another file mount created the same way, but in the fileadmin folder works.

*Why do the file mounts outside of fileadmin not work?*

Comment: Just a sidenote. It does not have to be a good idea to place files inside /uploads/ folder as this folder is managed internally by TYPO3.  Some routines/ext that clean orphan files in /uplaods/ folder can accidentally remove your files if there will be no reference to them.

Comment: Good remark. I will have a look at this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have searched for hours to get this one solved:

For file mounts to work outside of the fileadmin folder, you have to set a config variable in the install tool of Typo3.

Display the full configuration and search for:

```
 "lockRootPath"
```

Then enter an absolute path to the directory that you want to lock the user in. Most of the cases you will want to take the root of your Typo3 installation.

Comment: Wow. I just had the issue again, found the Answer here and tried to upvote it, when I realized I placed it here for me to find. Head -> Table.